# Getting the object of a singleton collection

Tags: java, collections

I want to get the object of a collection that I know has exactly one element (basically it's the reverse of what `Collections.singletonList()` does - but I don't know whether the collection is list/set/something else so I can't use `c.get(0)`).

Currently I use `c.iterator.next()`, wonder if there is already a method for that in Java or one of the common libraries (apache-commons, guava etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Iterables.getOnlyElement()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) (or `Iterables.getFirst()`, if collection can be empty) from Guava.

Comment: As of 2016/9/16 the link is broken. Use https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can do:

```
collection.stream().findAny().get();
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see a benchmark of this solution against `collection.iterator().next()`